# javascript : add some content in parentNode

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

What could be best way to add some content into ParentNode, if it has several child nodes without id.

the condition are :

```
 <div class="parent_div">
       <div class="child_div_1" >  I need to add contents inside this div </div> 

       <div class ="child_div_2" onmouseover="addClass(this)"> </div>
    </div> 

My possible solution :  function addClass(obj) {

       obj.parentNode.firstChild.appendChild(...);
    }
```

But i have doubt if someone changes the position of first child then what? according to you what could be best way to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JQuery :

```
function addClass(obj) {

       $(obj.parentNode)
               .find("ClassName_in_which_you_want_to_append")
                  .append("your_derived_contents");
   }
```

**Note :** ***find()*** it just look up the class_name whatever you want. Position doesn't matter. It just look up inside the parent node.

***append()*** : just add the contents as a child

I hope this helps you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand. There must be something determining which element you want to put the content in and, if that's the case, it should have an ID (a unique element deserves a unique field, right?)

If those class names that you've defined (`child_div_1`) are meaningful to the element in which you need to insert content, you can use the method `getElementsByClassName` to select the correct element.

```
function addClass(obj) {
  obj.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('child_div_1')[0].appendChild(/* ... */);
}
```

If the class names you've given in the example are just arbitrary, you're going to have to add some additional information to your block elements.

Comment: this is the only strict condition that i can't define the ID.

Comment: In which case, you'll have to use the class name (provided they are unique as per your example).

Answer (score 0):

please add the ids for those tags that you need to refer to, it's much easier and more accurate for your javascript code to run.